# How can I make my webapp work only with the https protocol?

Tags: angularjs, jelastic

We have a web application built with Angular, express and mariadb, and we want to access it just by using the https protocol, we do not want the http protocol to be available

Comment: I think https is set by the web server which hosts the application

Comment: To help us better understand your use case and suggest the best fit with Jelastic, we need to provide a topology of your environment with the stack version in use. Perhaps the solutions that are provided here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-https-redirect and here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-to-https will suit you.